# How to load the content based on the animation speed in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-animate

I am creating my own jquery slider.What I did is I have some images in the top as menu .Some of them are hided.So I have the next and previous button to show the remaining menus.
  Based on the menu selected (directly click on menu or using the next,prev button) I am displaying the content below that.

Everything went fine.Now I want to implement the animation.I am displaying the menu by adding css property left.

```
jQuery("#positionindicator").css({left : "+=" + imageWidth + "px"});
```

when I try to do with animation if the user clicks next or previous button **fast** the content loads slowly.For display the content I am calling the another function called `loadcontent`

```
jQuery("#"+i+"_slidecontent").show(); // for showing the content, similarly for hide the content too
```

So some times the menu selection indicated as another menu and content loaded for some other menu.

I want to achieve both in the same time even user **clicks continuously on the buttons**.

what I did is instead of css I tried with animate and I got the error what I mentioned the above scenario.

```
jQuery("#positionindicator").animate({left : "+=" + imageWidth + "px"});
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I am not sure why my screen shot is not showing here :(

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: @Dom sorry dom..I cant able to provide the code  :(

Comment: :(! Can you provide anything that will imitate the error?

Comment: have you tried specifying the `duration` property to see if it makes a difference?